# Check text in string

Tags: batch-file, substring

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET _STRING=image.pdf
SET _TEXT=.Pf

REM if delete next line
REM IF /I %_STRING:%_TEXT%=% NEQ %_STRING%  (ECHO. 'not equal') ELSE (ECHO. 'equal')

REM and insert value instead of variable
IF /I %_STRING:.Pf=% NEQ %_STRING%  (ECHO. 'not equal') ELSE (ECHO. 'equal')

PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Now output is correct

> ```
> 'equal'
> ```

Comment: remove `echo off` and watch how the code is executed. Then read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: `IF /I NOT "!_STRING:%_TEXT%=!" == "%_STRING%"` would be my first assumption!

Comment: @Compo line is correct, and I accepted in my batch, thanks

Comment: Now my batch is correct, by using @Compo line.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit, please do not change it to add an answer in the question area. If you want to post an answer yourself, please feel free to do so. Although it  would have been more courteous to give me the chance to convert my comment to an answer for you! Please also learn how to format your question, and any answer, I should not have to keep on editing your lack of formatting, especially of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my comment reproduced as an answer, together with the recommended syntax for defining variables using the `SET` command.

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    
    SET "_STRING=image.pdf"
    SET "_TEXT=.Pf"
    
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        
        IF /I NOT "!_STRING:%_TEXT%=!" == "%_STRING%" (ECHO= 'not equal') ELSE ECHO= 'equal'
        
    ENDLOCAL
    
    PAUSE
    
GOTO :EOF
```

I have also indented the code, to better highlight the sections which are working under different levels of `SETLOCAL`.